# Delegate dynamic replacement with blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, block

Inspired by idea of replacement `delegates` with `block` f.e like for `UIAlertView`

https://gist.github.com/puppybits/1523687

It is clear that delegates full-replacement impossible, but for such routine like `UIAlertView` where you need just one call-back handler imho that works fine.

I'm just wandering is there a way to have it dynamic and not related just to one `class`?

F.e BlockReplacement class is responsible for executing methods, receiving delegates and perform it in block.

something like this:

```
SomeObject *someObject = [[SomeObject alloc] init]; 
[BlockReplacement performSelector:@selector(doSomething:) 
                       ofObject:someObject 
                     blockHandler:doneBlock 
                forDelegateMethod:@selector(doneSomething:)];
```

there is a problem - someObject may has more then 1 delegate methods so then `blockHandler: forDelegateMethod` need to be something like `varargs`.

of course it's about runtime methods injection, does it sound like crazy, useless idea?